# Why cannot modify a value of an object in a CommonJS module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, es6-modules, template-literals

I have this basic `koa v2` app in which I try to implement template literals as a viewing engine. In `./views/index.js` how can I populate the value of `state` from `app.js`?

My problem is that I want to push the object values from `ctx.body = index.render({})` all the way down to `.views/partials/mainTop.js` file, where let's say I want to include `title` object value between the `<title></title>` tags. Is there a way to achieve this without requiring `.views/partials/mainTop.js` in `app.js`? I want to achieve similar thing with template literals if it were handlebars or nunjucks templates.

`./app.js`

```js
const index = require('./views/index');
const app = new Koa();

app.use(ctx => {
  index.state = {
    foo: 'bar',
  };
  ctx.body = index.render({
    title: 'Template Literals',
    description: 'Vanilla JS rendering',
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

`./views/index.js`

```js
const main = require('./layouts/main');

let state = {};
module.exports.state = state;
console.log(state); // returning an {} empty object, expected => { foo: "bar" }

module.exports.render = (obj) => {
  return main.render(`
    <p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>
    ${JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)}}
    ${obj.title}
  `);
};
```

`./views/layouts/main.js`

```js
const mainTop = require('../partials/mainTop');
const mainBottom = require('../partials/mainBottom');

module.exports.render = (content) => {
  return `
    ${mainTop.render}

    ${content}

    ${mainBottom()}
  `;
}
```

`./views/partials/mainTop.js`

```js
const render = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html class="no-js" lang="">
  <head>
  <title></title>
  ...
`;
module.exports.render = render;
```

`./views/partials/mainBottom.js`

```js
module.exports = () => {
  return `
    ...
    </body>
    </html>
  `;
}
```

Comment: unclear. you can define a anywhere-reachable method to return the value, or last resort, use a global.

Comment: I wonder why `mainTop` is defined as an object with a string property while `mainBottom` is defined as a function returning a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `console.log(state);` // returning an `{}` empty object, expected => `{ foo: "bar" }`

Of course you're getting the empty object you just created:

- it's the `module.exports.state` property that is getting assigned to in app.js. Your local `state` variable is not overwritten, nor is the object it refers to mutated. To do that, you'd need to do  `index.state.foo = "bar";` in index.js.
- the object/variable is logged immediately after it was created as an empty object. The assignment in index.js happens asynchronously, inside an `app.use` callback. If you did the `console.log` inside the render method, which is called *after* the assignment, you'd get the value as expected. However in that case you probably should just pass it as a parameter.